Degree of identity by descent with egg donated from a sibling?
If a woman becomes pregnant with an egg donated from her sister, what is the degree of identity by descent (IBD) between her and the child?
A pair of siblings have the following expected IBD probabilities:
P(IBD=0)=0.25

P(IBD=1)=0.5

P(IBD=2)=0.25

My solution therefore is:
So if we assume that recombination occurs at random so P(recomb)=0.5 and per haplotype there would be P(IBD=1)=0.75 (because one half is IBD=1 one quarter is IBD=2).
Then the result would be:
P(IBD=1) = P(IBD=1)*P(recomb) = 0.375.
So the result is the child and the mother would be:
P(IBD=0)=0.625

P(IBD=1)=0.375

P(IBD=2)=0.0

Is my inference correct?
